# Chrome wont show drop down unless browser is re sized or new tab is open?

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, menu

This problem has been rattling my brain for ages. Basically I have a simple drop down that activates off one link on hover state. However when you first load up the site in chrome (with no other tabs active) when you hover over the parent the sub-menu appears then the moment you try to move to select it, it disappears again. I've currently tried all different combinations of Display / Visibility and nothing has worked.

The site in question [deadpixelcreative](http://www.deadpixelcreative.com)

The stranger part is that if you re-size the browser or open another tab the menu works fine?

I'm at a total loss and any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**.CSS**

```
#cssmenu {


font-family: 'AlternateGothicCom-No2', sans-serif;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top: 0px;
  z-index:100;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
  display: none; }
  /* Hide for large screens */

#norm {}

#cssmenu > ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  color:#fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
  visibility:hidden;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  float:left;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #D9EE27;

}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  color:#333;
  font-size:16px;
}

#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li > a:hover{
  color:#fff;
}

#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% -95%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
  background-position: 90% 195%;
  color:#333;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px 11px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
  background: #D9EE27;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need `float:left;` in your `#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul` ? That might be a possible cause. Not easy to debug this case ^^

Comment: I've removed it :) as its not needed, I forgot to take it out when I was trying different solutions. Sadly though the problem remains!

Comment: It's really hard to find a solution to this issue without any way to test something (JSFiddle doesn't reproduce the problem). The only advise that I can give you, is to restart from the begining, without css for your ul li.has-sub & ul li.has-sub ul, and trying to rebuilt it step by step until the problem appear. At first sight, it could be a 1px margin or something like this that is escaping the "hover" statement. It maybe be caused by the zoom:1, position:fixed, ... Sorry, I cannot do much more for you :( Good luck !

Comment: Seems to work fine on my Chrome (41.0.2272.101m).

Answer (score 0):

I played around a little bit, it is actually not easy to debug because when I open Chrome developer tool to make changes, problem disappears. I found the following and I hope one them work since I could not actually check it myself.

1. div#cssmenu has a height of 38px because anchor tags have padding top 12px, padding bottom 11px and line height of 15px. For some reason in some views div#cssmenu's height changes to 37px while anchor tags remain 38px. The top property of fixed positioned 'li.has-sub > ul' is being calculated by the browser which maybe the problem because of an unknown margin or something, try:

   li.has-sub ul {top : 37px}
2. '#wrapper' is not actually wrapping anything since its width is defined by the browser as 0px. Also it is at the top of the page, the only reason it is not covering the top is its '-1' z-index. Try to make it how it is suppose to be.

If adding 'top: 37px' causes problem with your website being responsive try having it in a @media.

The other thing that is worth mentioning is when you have @media for views in mobile devices remember that you no longer have on hover state for touch screen devices for your drop down menu.

Hope it solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue on a coworker's laptop. I had the same latest version of Chrome on Windows (Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and yet I didn't see the issue. I found an obscure reference (on salesforce) about a Chrome issue with cross-origin iframes and cut-off dropdown text (which yes, this dropdown is on a cross-origin iframe on our webpage).
I applied the fix below to laptop and the webpage shows up as it should.

> "Windows specific issue - Dropdown lists are rendered based on the DPI
>   scaling of the main display.
>
> Chromium KI:
>
> Issue 877625: Dropdown input in cross-origin iframes render with the
>   DPI scaling of the main monitor in Windows
>
> In order to replicate this issue you must have multiple displays, and
>   your main display must be set to a different DPI scaling level from
>   your external display. If the DPI on your main display is larger than
>   the DPI on your external display, the dropdown options will appear cut
>   off when the list is opened. Alternatively, if your external display
>   DPI scale is larger then there will be a large blank area in the
>   dropdown when rendered.
>
> As a workaround, you can set all monitors to the same DPI scale
>   setting. To do so right click on your Desktop and select Display
>   settings, then under Scale and Layout make sure the value is the same
>   for the field Change the size of text, apps, and other items on all
>   displays."